# Response object not usable in WCF?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, response

I'm creating a silverlight-based email system, I use WCF to read emails, then I pass my data to SL app, I've used following codes in another test web project to save a byte array into a file on client system (email attachments), it works fine, but when I want to use them in my WCF (myservice.svc.cs), I get this error: "The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context", what is going wrong here? is it possible to use Response object in a service?

```
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", messages[i].Attachments[j].FileName));
                    Response.BinaryWrite(messages[i].Attachments[j].FileData);
```

how can I save my attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you typically would not use an HttpResponse object in WCF (though I am not 100% sure if you *could* use it in REST services or not).  If you want to send a file to the client, you'll need to implement a service operation that returns a byte array or a file stream. This [post](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/) might help you with that.

Comment: thanks, you mean I should just return my byte array instead of writing it into stream? I'm using this service in Silverlight, then how can I use this returned byte array to save my file in SL?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet you can use the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx) class, which can give you a file stream to write to, and you can write the contents of the array to that file stream.

Comment: the SaveFileDialog gives you a FileStream, and you'd use the FileStream.Write method to write your byte array.

Comment: the file is created, but nothing is written in this file, how can I write something?

Comment: Try calling the FileStream.Flush and FileStream.Close methods **after** you write the bytes to the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try it, but as I said this process is going to download email attachments, and I have file names and extensions myself, is there any way that I can explicitly set filename? something like ASP.NET response client file save dialog?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet SL won't let you save a file without having the user select a file location, name and extension (it's a security feature). However, SaveFileDialog does have DefaultFileName and DefaultExt properties you can play with.